# Try to migrate data from Intent to ListView, but there are some error

Tags: java, android, firebase, listview, android-intent

I already was helped with this problem, but now, when I run app, this mistake is come. 2 hours later all was fine, but I didn't change anything, what is that?? I try to take data from Firestore, and get it to ListView, and that to next activity.

Error:

> Process: com.example.eugene.lafinalproduction, PID: 9741
>       java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: n <= 0: 0
>           at java.util.Random.nextInt(Random.java:182)
>           at com.example.eugene.lafinalproduction.ListViewPlaces$1.onComplete(ListViewPlaces.java:63)
>           at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzj.run(Unknown Source)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5763)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)

Error in this line:

```
randomPlaceList.add(placesList.get(randomGenerator.nextInt(placeCount)));
```

Main activity:

```
public class ListViewPlaces extends AppCompatActivity {

FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionReference placesRef = rootRef.collection("Places");

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_view_places);

    placesRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                List<Places> placesList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                    Places places = document.toObject(Places.class);

                    placesList.add(places);
                }
                if (placesList.size() > 0) {
                    int placeCount = placesList.size();
                    System.out.println(placesList.size());
                    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
                    List<Places> randomPlaceList = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
                        String randomIndex = randomGenerator.nextInt(randomPlaceList.size());
                        randomPlaceList.add(randomIndex);
                        ListView mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.place_list);
                        PlacesAdapter placesAdapter = new PlacesAdapter(getApplicationContext(), randomPlaceList);
                        mListView.setAdapter(placesAdapter);
                    }
                }
        }
    }
});
```

}
}

Model class:

```
    public class Places {
    private String name;

    public Places() {

    }

    public Places(String name) {

        this.name = name;


    }


    public String getName() { return name; }
```

My adapter:

```
    class PlaceAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Places> {

private ArrayList<Places> dataSet;
Context mContext;

private static class ViewHolder {
    TextView name_text;
    ImageView image_text;
}

public PlaceAdapter(ArrayList<Places> dataSet, Context context ) {
    super(context, R.layout.item_list, dataSet);

    this.dataSet = dataSet;
    this.mContext = context;

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View converView, ViewGroup parent) {

    Places places = getItem(position);
    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    final View result;

    if (converView == null) {
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        converView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list, parent, false);
        viewHolder.name_text = (TextView) converView.findViewById(R.id.text_image_id);
        viewHolder.image_text = (ImageView) converView.findViewById(R.id.image_id);

        result = converView;

        converView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) converView.getTag();
        result = converView;
    }

    viewHolder.name_text.setText(places.getName());
    Glide.with(getContext()).load(places.getImage()).into(viewHolder.image_text);

    return converView;
```

And second activity:

```
public class Card_activity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    TextView mTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.massive_places);

        mTextView = findViewById(R.id.head_name);
        String name = getIntent().getStringExtras("name")
        mTextView.setText(name);
    }
}
```

Comment: update error line

Comment: I upate the answer in Main Activity@Eminem

Comment: Yes, it's mistake that now in my project@Eminem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int placeCount = placesList.size();
```

[nextInt(int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-) produces a number from 0 to n. For instance, nextInt(3) might produce 0, 1 or 2. So, values <= 0 just don't make sense. Which means that if `placecount` is <= 0 it throws exception!To test it print placeCount and watch what the variable returns!

*bound - the upper bound (exclusive). Must be positive.*
Edit:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    if (placeCount >0) {
        randomPlaceList.add(placesList.get(randomGenerator.nextInt(placeCount)));          
    }
}
```

Another way would be:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) { 
       int randomIndex = randomGenerator.nextInt(randomPlaceList.size()); 
       Places item = randomPlaceList.get(randomIndex); 
       randomPlaceList.add(item); 
}
```